# How to put a Rails error.each element in a Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to put a Rails element in a Jquery select so I don't do it manually, the point is, I have this piece of code:

```
<% @task.errors.each do |elem, b| %>

<% end %>
```

and I was trying to do this

```
<% @task.errors.each do |elem, b| %>
    $(elem).addClass("input is-danger");
<% end %>
```

because elem represents an id, I already tried concatenating it like this:

```
$("#".concat(elem.to_s)).addClass(...);
```

but it did not work out, is this even possible, if yes, how? Thank you further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put jquery selectors into loops (or HTML). Instead you write HTML and target those elements with JQuery.

For example:

file.html.erb

```
<% @task.errors.each do |elem| %>
  <div class="input">
    ...stuff...
  </div>    
<% end %>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input').addClass('danger');
})
```